# Number of Snapshot Agent, Log reader Agent, Distributor Agent jobs would be possible

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server replication and willing to understand regarding agent jobs

Suppose, we have Pub_Server(Multiple databases + Multiple publications + Multiple Subscription), Dist_Server, Sub_Server with Push Subscription.

I am willing to understand, how many Snapshot Agent, Log reader Agent, Distributor Agent jobs would be possible in this situation.

Any resource with practical implementation would be really helpful.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I mean, If i am creating multiple publication for different databases, then do we need multiple log reader, snapshot agent and distributor agent as well.

Comment: I think you might want to read up about replication agents. You need to understand what they are and how they are used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/agents/replication-agents